# URL making a letter capitalized, when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation button `Products` that brings you to this link:

```
"/default.aspx?page=category"
```

It's typed exactly like that, so no capitals. But on the website when you click `Products` it comes out like this:

```
"/default.aspx?Page=category"
```

with a capital P. If you click the link twice it goes back to

```
"/default.aspx?page=category"
```

but I don't know how to force it to be lowercase when it's hardcoded as lowercase already. I do work with jquery so I know I'll need jquery to check if it contains uppercase letters but the answers I've seen for my question don't seem to help me. I'm still a beginner, but I'm getting there. You can see it in action [here](http://estore.peirce.com) by clicking on `Products` but here's my code:

```
 <ul id="SubHeader">
      <li><a href="/default.aspx?page=category">Products</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="/?page=brands list">Brands</a></li><!--
   --><li class="DesktopOnly"><a href="/?page=customer&file=customer/pephin/customerpages/AboutUs.htm">About Us</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="/customer/pephin/customerpages/contactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Something is going on server when you use the aspx file name, I tried with only `/?page=category`, as in your other links and that works fine, so I'm sure there is a rewrite rule that does this

Comment: There seems to be redirect from https:// to http://, check your redirects as these change the url.

Comment: I now made a second test, so if you, from main page, add `default.aspx` to the Branch link the same issue occurs, which confirms what I said in above comment